# statistics and probability textbook for data science and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, references

I want to learn statistics and probability for machine learning and data science, and I'm don't know what textbook I should use for self-study. Now my choice is between

1. The Elements of Statistical Learning - Trevor Hastie

or

2. Fundamentals of Probability:
   A First Course and Probability for Statistics

and
Machine Learning - Anirban DasGupta

or

3. "Introduction to Probability" by Joseph K. Blitzstein

and
Jessica Hwang and "Statistics" by Robert S. Witte and John S. together

Question is what is difference between 3 choice and what I should use for self-study in Machine Learning, Data science field.

Comment: I would also have a look at Bishop's Peattern recognition and machine learning, as well as MacKay's book on information theory.